# POST request error: Path `title` and `body` are required

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm trying to make a POST request to my server to create a new post (title, body) and save it in the db and I'm receiving a 200 status code however the title and body aren't being inserted into a post.

UPDATE: I have just changed `return res.status(400).json({ error: errorHandler(err) })` in the controller method to `res.send(err)` and now I'm receiving a clear error message: The title and body paths are required.

How can I solve this?

CreatePost.js

```
 class CreatePost extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)
     
         this.state = {
              title: '',
              body: ''
         }
     }
     
     changeHandler = (e) => {
         this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
     }
     

     submitHandler = e => {
         e.preventDefault()
         axios.post(`${API}/blog/post/create`, this.state)
         .then(response => {
             console.log(response)
         }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error)
         })
     }
    render() {
        const {title, body} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <input type="text" name="title" 
                onChange={this.changeHandler} value={title} />
                <input type="text" name="body"
                onChange={this.changeHandler} value={body}/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CreatePost
```

controllers/post.js

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let post = new Post()
  post.save((err, result) => {
    if(err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler(err)
    })
    }
    res.json(result)
    })
}
```

routes/posts.js

```
router.post('/blog/post/create', create);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. I wasn't actually inserting the title and body into the post object.

I destructured `title` and `body` from `req.body`: 
`const {title, body} = req.body` 
 and inserted the data into the object `let post = new Post({title, body})`.

controllers/posts.js

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const {title, body} = req.body
  let post = new Post({title, body})

  post.save()
  .then(response => {
  res.send(response)
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
})
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to call your endpoint from [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) (my favorite) to verify it is up and running? This is a great method to test your endpoints independently from your code.

Since you don't use HTTP 404 in your code, I suspect it is coming from the inner mechanisms of Express.

By the way, the verb POST and the 'create' part in your API uri are stating the same intent. You could get rid of this create part. This is considered one of the [best practices](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I receive a 404 error in Postman too. Thanks, I'll remove `create` from the uri.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
axios({ url: `${API}/blog/post/create`, method: 'POST', data: this.state})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this hasn't worked for me. @Kevin Li